# Can a system image disk be also used as a bootable system restore disk in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore

As the title says, can I use a system image disk as also a bootable system restore disk in Win 7 (I am using the built in utility in Win 7 to create the system image disk) ?

And even if I use a separate system restore disk, is it possible to restore the system from an image stored in multiple DVDs. (I have a single DVD drive in my computer)

Comment: Depends on what software created the image in the first place, we need more specifics.

Comment: @Moab I have have provided the details in my question.

Comment: You have to first boot from a "system repair disc", then this has tools to restore the windows image you made. I have never tried to combine these into one disc, so I don't know if this is possible.